# Combine overlapping ranges of numbers

Tags: python, numbers, range, overlap

I need to combine overlapping ranges of numbers into single range. So I have a list with sub-lists of something like:

```
[[83,77],[103,97],[82,76],[101,95],[78,72],[97,91],[72,66],[89,83],[63,57],[78,72],[53,47],[65,59],[41,35],[50,44],[28,22],[34,28],[14,8],[16,10]]
```

So from 83 to 77 is overlapping 82 to 76 and will become 76 to 83. If any other ranges overlap this range would ad it's minimum of maximum to this range, and when there no others that overlap then the method should go to the next one in the list and try to merge that with it's overlappings.

I hoop this makes sense.

Comment: add* minimum or maximum*

Comment: Pls post the output you expect and your current attempt to get there.

Comment: I'm new to python and sitting with this problem quite a long time, because I can't wrap my mind around the logic. I don't have an attempt, that's why I ask for help in the first place. And I've also described what I do expect as output. Thank you in advance for understanding.

Comment: You only say "will become 76 to 83". Does that mean your output should be `[[76, 83], ...]`? Are the pairs in the original always ordered descendingly, and do you expect the result pairs to be ascending?

Comment: First, thank you for reacting! Yes, the point it to optimize/compact the list so that the ranges that that overlap are merged. So those two wil become one and if any other overlap with them wil be also added and so 3 sub-lists wil become 1. The order in which the list comes is not specified so it can be as descending or ascending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this:

```
from itertools import combinations
l = [[83,77],[103,97],[82,76],[101,95],[78,72],[97,91],[72,66],[89,83],[63,57],[78,72],[53,47],[65,59],[41,35],[50,44],[28,22],[34,28],[14,8],[16,10]]


def any_items_overlap(l):

    # For each possible pair of lists in l
    for item1, item2 in combinations(l, 2):

        max1, min1 = item1
        max2, min2 = item2

        if min1 > max2 or max1 < min2:
            # no overlap so ignore this pair
            continue

        else:  # One of the combinations overlaps, so return them
            return item1, item2

    return None


while True:

    if not any_items_overlap(l):
        # No items overlapped - break the loop and finish
        print(l)
        break

    else:  # There are still overlaps
        item1, item2 = any_items_overlap(l)

        # Remove the items from the main list
        l.remove(item1)
        l.remove(item2)

        # Replace them with a merged version
        item_values = item1 + item2
        l.append([max(item_values), min(item_values)])
        # Start the loop again to check for any other overlaps
```

This gives:

```
[[41, 35], [103, 91], [65, 57], [53, 44], [34, 22], [16, 8], [89, 66]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much the solution worked! Now I'll be out for a week, because I'm dum dum  and I need a lot of time to understand that this code does... Never the less much obliged!

Comment: No problem - I've added some comments to explain what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Use an IntervalTree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

There is an implementation available in python:

```
pip install intervaltree
```

```
import intervaltree

intervals = [
    [77, 83],
    [97, 103],
    [76, 82],
    [95, 101],
    [72, 78],
    [91, 97],
    [66, 72],
    [83, 89],
    [57, 63],
    [72, 78],
    [47, 53],
    [59, 65],
    [35, 41],
    [44, 50],
    [22, 28],
    [28, 34],
    [8, 14],
    [10, 16],
]

tree = intervaltree.IntervalTree.from_tuples(intervals)

print(tree)
tree.merge_overlaps()
print(tree)
tree.merge_overlaps(strict=False)
print(tree)
```

note that I had to make your points be `(start, end)` instead of `(end, start)`.

```
IntervalTree([Interval(8, 14), Interval(10, 16), Interval(22, 28), Interval(28, 34), Interval(35, 41), Interval(44, 50), Interval(47, 53), Interval(57, 63), Interval(59, 65), Interval(66, 72), Interval(72, 78), Interval(76, 82), Interval(77, 83), Interval(83, 89), Interval(91, 97), Interval(95, 101), Interval(97, 103)])
```

is merged to

```
IntervalTree([Interval(8, 16), Interval(22, 28), Interval(28, 34), Interval(35, 41), Interval(44, 53), Interval(57, 65), Interval(66, 72), Interval(72, 83), Interval(83, 89), Interval(91, 103)])
```

and with `strict=False` allowing touching intervals to be merged

```
IntervalTree([Interval(8, 16), Interval(22, 34), Interval(35, 41), Interval(44, 53), Interval(57, 65), Interval(66, 89), Interval(91, 103)])
```

Comment: Thank you as well, for explanation and help!

Comment: Wanted to note that if you are using a large number of intervals this is much more reliable.  A customized version of the logic would allow additional improvements, since you only want merged values, but it should be `~|size of list|` times faster than the combinations or nested for loops.

Comment: Noted! Thank you once more for the additional information!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one naive way:

```
l = [[83,77],[103,97],[82,76],[101,95],[78,72],[97,91],[72,66],[89,83],[63,57],[78,72],[53,47],[65,59],[41,35],[50,44],[28,22],[34,28],[14,8],[16,10]]
new_l = []
contained = False
for i,subl in enumerate(l):
    mini, maxi = min(subl), max(subl)
    for subl2 in l:
        if mini in range(subl2[1],subl2[0]+1):
            mini = subl2[1]
        elif maxi in range(subl2[1],subl2[0]+1):
            maxi = subl2[0]
    if len(new_l)>1:
        for subl3 in new_l:
            contained = False
            if mini in range(subl3[0],subl3[1]+1) or maxi in range(subl2[0],subl2[1]+1):
                contained = True
                break
    if contained == True: continue
    new_l.append([mini,maxi])
print(new_l)
```

Output:

```
[[66, 89], [91, 103], [57, 65], [44, 53], [35, 41], [22, 34], [8, 16]]
```