# finding an union of intersecting elements in a list of segments

Tags: python

I have a segments list:

```
lst = [[1,5],[2,7],[8,13],[12,15],[3,4]]
```

First and second elements intersect, so i combine them and so on.I need to get this list:

```
lst1 = [[1,7],[8,15]]
```

I have problem when 3 or more segments intersect with ourselves.
I tried to fill the missing numbers, and find union using sets

```
unions = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(i,len(lst)):
        if len(list(set(lst[i]) & set(lst[j]))) != 0:
            unions.append(list(set(lst[i]) | set(lst[j])))
```

but I think it is wrong way.How can I do this without using any libraries?

Comment: Are the endpoints of the segments inclusive or exclusive? (e.g. if I have `[[8, 12], [12, 14]]`, what is the desired output?)

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I don't have those items but output will be [8,14]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging Overlapping Intervals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071081/merging-overlapping-intervals-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging Overlapping Intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43600878/6045800)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine overlapping ranges of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58535825/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- sort the array by start points of the segments.
- make one pass through the array. For each segment, if the start point is strictly greater than the previous segment's end point, then that segment marks the beginning of a new segment in the merged output. Otherwise, merge it with the previous segment.

Here is the code implementing this algorithm:

```py
import math

def get_union(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []

    sorted_list = sorted(lst)
    merged_intervals = []
    [start, end] = lst[0]

    for index, interval in enumerate(sorted_list):
        [current_interval_start, current_interval_end] = interval
        if end < current_interval_start:
            merged_intervals.append([start, end])
            start = current_interval_start
            end = current_interval_end
        else:
            end = current_interval_end

    merged_intervals.append([start, end])

    return merged_intervals
```

This runs in `O(n log n)` time, because sorting the array takes `O(n log n)` time, and the merging process takes linear time. This is faster than using two nested `for` loops as done in your approach (which takes quadratic time).

Comment: Please consider removing this answer as this question is a duplicate. If your answer doesn't exist in the [dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43600878/6045800), please post it there